# How to forward and mask particular folder of domain to new domain in aws Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, mask, forward

```
[www.example.com/xyz][1] is my domain
xyz is the folder where wordpress is installed.
I have a instance which holds xyz like www.aaa.com/xyz
I want to access [www.aaa.com/xyz][2] with www.example.com/xyz calls
and the url should look like www.example.com/xyz
Simply 
I want to migrate the wordpress to new instance but URL should remain same 
The [www.example.com][1] is a laravel website which is placed inside an ALB.
/xyz folder have wordpress 


  [1]: http://www.example.com
```

Any help is highly appreciated.Can I achieve this using ALB configurations or i need to do something with apache and htaccess or need to make changes in Route53.

Comment: why don't you switch the old instance with the new instance in the elb?

Comment: We are facing DDOS attack and cannot able to get IP of the user as it is inside ALB. So we want to separate our blog url to new instance to detect the attack is for blog or main site, but issue is coming that how i can redirect the user to the blog url and domain should remain same.As google already indexed our blog. We are running 2r4.large machines , i.e. 32GB RAM it get full and our server dies. We made a patch for some time , but i want to resolve the problem completely.